# when i compile it give me this error can anyone help me?

Tags: c

this is code written in c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "simpio.h"
#include "genlib.h"
#include <stdbool.h>

bool Valid_Time(int h,int min,int sec);

int main()
{
   int h,min,sec;

   printf("Dwse tis ores: ");
   h=GetInteger();
   printf("Dwse ta lepta: ");
   min=GetInteger();
   printf("Dwse ta defterolepta: ");
   sec=GetInteger();
   if ( Valid_Time (int h,int min,int sec) == true)
   {
       printf("Valid: yes");
   }
   else
   {
       printf("Valid: no");
   }
   return 0;
}

bool Valid_Time(int h,int min,int sec)
{
    bool valid;

    valid=true;
    if(h<0 || h>23)
    {
        valid=false;
    }
    if(min<0 || min>59)
    {
        valid=false;
    }
    if(sec<0 || sec>59)
    {
        valid=false;
    }
    return valid;
}
```

error:expected expession befor 'int'
error:too few arguments to function 'Valid_Time'

i cant undersand why there is an error

why does this error pop up

Comment: `if ( Valid_Time (int h,int min,int sec) == true)` Who taught you to call a function like that?  What are those extra `int` keywords doing there?

Comment: In the if statement, `Valid_Time (int h,int min,int sec)` isn't the right syntax for a function call. You should not specify the types there. Please try finding that line and [edit] your post with any further compile errors you get.

Comment: C is not a language you can learn by trial and error.

Comment: JELO, review function calls `printf("Dwse tis ores: ")` and `GetInteger()`.  Do you see any _type_ name there?  Do likewise with call `Valid_Time (int h,int min,int sec)` and drop the 3 `int`.

Comment: JELO, also do not compare a function that returns `bool` with `true`.  Just use `if ( Valid_Time (/* fixed code here */))`.  No ` == true`.

Comment: @SteveSummit Comments [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74536764/when-i-compile-it-give-me-this-error-can-anyone-help-me#comment131574269_74536764), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74536764/when-i-compile-it-give-me-this-error-can-anyone-help-me#comment131574287_74536764) focus on the OP and not the question.  Best, and more polile, to focus on the question and not the questioner.

Comment: Hello again everyone sorry for my obvious mistakes i am new to c and i try to learn on my own in my free time thank you for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function call has type parameters in your usage.  Remove the type specification when using the function.

Try this

```
Valid_Time (h,min,sec) == true
```

Comment: or simply `Valid_Time(h,min,sec)` without the `== t`.

Comment: Indeed.  I meant to say true since I wanted to show the usage line.  Let me edit to add the true.

Comment: chux's point is that it's better to *leave off* the `== true` part.

Comment: Yes indeed.  Like I try to convey.  I was simply showing the OP the place to make the change.